# JPA join column only for insert/delete , disable select

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have `@OneToMAny` realationship inside my entity.

Is it possible to disable jpa from generating select for the joined column? beacuse I have many records in my main table and when selecting them , each record performs select for the joined column. I would like to disable this select is that possible?

**UPDATE:**
I tried inserting fetch LAZY but it still creates a select for Table02f and Table03f...

This is my code:

```
 public class Table01f implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "table01f")
    private List<Table02f> table02fList;

    //getter & setter...
}

public class Table02f implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "F2PRP", referencedColumnName = "F1PRP", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Table01f table01f;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY , cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "table02f")
    private List<Table03f> table03fList;

    //getter & setter...
}

public class Table03f implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "F3PRP", referencedColumnName = "F2PRP", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "F3BRN", referencedColumnName = "F2BRN", insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Table02f table02f;

//getter & setter...
}
```

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the fetch type `LAZY` to your `@OneToMany` relationship:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

When you load the list of your main entities, JPA won't populate your list for this relationship, avoiding the generation of the `SELECT`.

Just have a look at this functionality in JPA documentation so that you can understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the data make it LAZY (in general always make everything LAZY).

If you need the data, then you can use batch fetching, or join fetching.

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

Comment: You may also consider using a fetch-group or only selecting the field you want in JPQL.